# What is the difference between the QueryParser and the API?

Tags: lucene.net

On step 3 of [this tutorial](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx) the author writes:

> I personally would use the QueryParser when the search string is supplied by the user, and I’d use directly the API when the query is generated by your code.

Are there any benefits of using one over the other or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the link says, if you want to allow users to enter custom searches as text string (i.e Name:matt, Age:[10 TO 80] use the QueryParser.

However if you only need to allow pre-defined queries, you can create them directly in your code.

So it depends what sort of queries you are using and how they are made, by the user, pre-defined etc